# How download Excel file in Vue.js application correctly?

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, blob, xlsx

I'm struggling to download an `Excel` file in `xlsx` format in my `Vue.js` application. My Vue.js application make post request to the Node.js application which download that Excel file from remote SFTP server. Backend application works without any problems.

In Vue.js application I use next code:

```js
axios.post(config.backendHost + '/excel', {
  file_name: fileName
}).then((response) => {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {
    type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
  }))
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = url
  link.setAttribute('download', fileName)
  document.body.appendChild(link)
  link.click()
});
```

After downloading file by browser, file opens automatically and I am experiencing an error that looks like this:

> We found a problem with some content `.xlsx`. Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I was stuck here for hours

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to add the response type as a third argument in your *post* call

```js
{
    responseType: 'blob'
}
```

Your final code like that

```
axios.post(config.backendHost + '/excel', {
    file_name: fileName
}, {
    responseType: 'blob'
}).then((response) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {
        type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
    }))
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = url
    link.setAttribute('download', fileName)
    document.body.appendChild(link)
    link.click()
});
```

Or you can use the library FileSaver.js to save your file

```
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'

axios.post(config.backendHost + '/excel', {
    file_name: fileName
}, {
    responseType: 'blob'
}).then((response) => {

    // response.data is a blob type
    FileSaver.saveAs(response.data, fileName);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I use first option which you described in your post and it works for me. Can I ask you one more question?! During the download, is it possible to change the style inside the excel file? For example, I want the header to be highlighted in a different color. Is it even possible for your opinion?

Comment: I don't think if you can do any modifications on the fly, but you can manipulate your file on the server side (NodeJS in your case) before downloading.

Comment: Any recommendation on how to write a unit test for this?

Comment: @Tom i'm not sure where the problem lies in unit testing this ? If your test always returns the same file, you can hash it using a hashing algorithm like MD5 (fast but weak due to collisions) and just verify in the test that the file returned has that same hash digest

Comment: FWIW: I needed to say `{responseType: 'arraybuffer'}`, not `{responseType: 'blob'}`. I was sending a .XLSX file from Django as an HttpResponse.

Answer (score 3):

my case worked:

```
  axios.get(`/api/v1/companies/${companyId}/export`, {
    responseType: 'blob',
  }).then((response) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = url
    link.setAttribute(
      'download',
      `${companyId}-${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}.xlsx`
    )
    document.body.appendChild(link)
    link.click()
  })
```